# Plotly Dash Integration with Django : The current path, welcome.html, didn’t match any of these While Applying Navigation on Sidebar

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I have followed [this Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psvU4zwO3Ao), and successfully applied all the step and executed. It is working fine. I am now trying to add navigation on the side bar like **tables** on the bottom of this sidebar navigational menu: but it is giving the following error: [image]

My master **urls.py** is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include    
urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('home.urls')),
        path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),
    ]
```

and my application **urls.py** is this:

```
from django import urls
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from home.dash_apps.finished_apps import simpleexample

urlpatterns= [

    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('tables/', views.home1, name='home1')
    
]
```

While my **sidebar.html** is as follows:

```
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home1' %}">
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-table"></i>
            <span>Tables</span></a>
    </li>
```

Moreover i am rendering this in the **views.py**

```
def home1(request):
    def scatter():
        x1 = ['PM2.5','PM10','CO2','NH3']
        y1 = [30, 35, 25, 45]

        trace = go.Scatter(
            x=x1,
            y = y1
        )
        layout = dict(
            title='Line Chart: Air Quality Parameters',
            xaxis=dict(range=[min(x1), max(x1)]),
            yaxis = dict(range=[min(y1), max(y1)])
        )

        fig = go.Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout)
        plot_div = plot(fig, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs=False)
        return plot_div

    context ={
        'plot1': scatter()
    }

    return render(request, 'home/welcome.html', context)
```

I am unable to understand how can I correctly locate the welcome.html so that it can be loaded when i click on Tables in side bar of dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url is wrong, you need follow the url defined by URL:

```
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('tables/', views.home1, name='home1')
```

Try:

```
172.20.43.46.8001/tables/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It is working now, but I have used all those combinations before posting this question which you have suggested. At that time that was not being working, but later i have restarted the development server and manually edited the url as you suggested /tables/ and it started working even i click on Tables on side bar menu. Does it necessary that at first you have to manually edit the URL and later from button? Isnt its insane?

Comment: you been use a template name in your url, because of that i said was wrong, and cool that solved your problem.